# Сохранение данных HTML-таблицы при ее повторном рендеринге

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я создаю таблицу, вводя количество строк и ячеек в поля `input`. Потом я вписываю в ячейки нужную информацию. Потом я хочу увеличить количество строк на 1, переписывая увеличивая значение в input на 1. В этом случае вся введённая мной информация в таблице теряется. Как сделать, чтобы она сохранялась???

```js
let out = document.getElementById('out');
let inputRow = document.getElementById('inputRow');
let inputCell = document.getElementById('inputCell');

inputRow.addEventListener('input', draw);
inputCell.addEventListener('input', draw)

function draw() {
  out.innerHTML = inputRow.value;
  for (i = 0; i < inputRow.value; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement('div');
    row.contentEditable = true;
    out.appendChild(row);
    for (j = 0; j < inputCell.value; j++) {
      let section = document.createElement('section');
      section.contentEditable = true;
      row.appendChild(section);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
out {
    display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
div {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
section {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  min-width: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
div:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
}
input {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
article {
  border: 3px dashed orange;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
button {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Количество строк" id="inputRow">
<input type="text" placeholder="Количество ячеек" id="inputCell">

<p id="out"></p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Привяжи к каждой ячейке координаты типа `X` и `Y`. По этим координатам можно отследить на какую именно ячейку ты нажал и что ввел в поле, через слушателей. На каждое нажатие ввода текста записываешь/перезаписывай массив объектов с координатами и значениями, а при построении таблицы считываешь данные с этого же массива объектов.

### Пример:

```js
let out = document.querySelector('#out');
let inputRow = document.querySelector('#inputRow');
let inputCell = document.querySelector('#inputCell');

inputRow.addEventListener('input', draw);
inputCell.addEventListener('input', draw)

function draw() {
  out.innerHTML = inputRow.value;
  for (let i = 0; i < inputRow.value; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement('div');
    row.contentEditable = true;
    out.appendChild(row);
    for (let j = 0; j < inputCell.value; j++) {
      let section = document.createElement('section');
      section.setAttribute('data-x', i);
      section.setAttribute('data-y', j);
      section.innerHTML = restoreValue(i, j, cellValues);
      section.contentEditable = true;
      row.appendChild(section);
    }
  }
}

function restoreValue(x, y, array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].x == x && array[i].y == y) {
      return array[i].value;
    }
  }
  return '';
}


let cellValues = [];
let outputGrid = document.querySelector('#out');
outputGrid.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let currentCell = e.target;
  let currentX = e.target.dataset.x;
  let currentY = e.target.dataset.y;
  let block = e.target.closest('div');
  block.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    let currentValue = currentCell.innerHTML == '<br>' ? '' : currentCell.innerHTML;
    let currentObj = {
      x: currentX,
      y: currentY,
      value: currentValue
    };
    cellValues = changeObjArray(cellValues, currentObj);
  })
});

function changeObjArray(array, obj) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].x == obj.x && array[i].y == obj.y) {
      if (obj.value) {
        array[i].value = obj.value;
        return array;
      } else {
        array.splice(i, 1);
        return array;
      }
    }
  }
  array.push(obj);
  return array;
}
```

```css
out {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

div {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

section {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  min-width: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
}

input {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

article {
  border: 3px dashed orange;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

button {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Количество строк" id="inputRow">
<input type="text" placeholder="Количество ячеек" id="inputCell">

<p id="out"></p>
```

Сыроватый пример, но главное рабочий)